# Detecting deviation of one time-series variable from a set of others

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have several streams of time-series data representing sensor readings that are usually closely correlated (at least in the casual usage of the term) though with different scalar multipliers applied. For example, say I have time-series A, B, and C representing historical sensor readings over time. B might be consistently around 75% of A, and C might be consistently around 50% of A. The absolute values change frequently, but the ratios between A / B / C remain fairly constant.

My goal is to detect points in time when one of these variables deviates significantly from the others. For example, I want to be able to detect if B's readings drop significantly in relation to A's and C's. The number of variables being compared might be anywhere between 3 and the low hundreds.

A sketch of what I'm thinking (which may be totally off-base): build a model based on historical data that allows me to predict the values of the target variable based on the values of the other variables. Use the model to predict what the value of the target variable should be for a certain time period, and compare to the actual value for that time period. If the delta between prediction based on historical data and actual reading is large enough, mark the time range as anomalous.

While that sounds reasonable to me, I have no idea how to go about:
1 - Building the predictive model from historical data, or
2 - Comparing the predicted and actual values and applying a test of some kind to determine whether the deviation is significant

Can anyone recommend approaches for either of these issues?